# Gathering information from parent record to child records

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which has ids as m_id and child_id, both are inter-connected as follows :

| m_id | child_id | op_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | finish |
| 2 | null | finish |
| 3 | null | finish |
| 4 | 1 | on-going |

In this example, m_id => 1 has two op_status as "finish" and "on-going". Another table is also joined with m_id for this table as follows :

| c_id | m_id | make | model | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | Acer | Aspire | 1 |
| 101 | 1 | Acer | Aspire | 1 |

Then I need to get the following output for the using these 02 tables as follows :

| m_id | child_id | make | model | op_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Acer | Aspire | finish |
| 2 | null | Acer | Aspire | finish |
| 3 | null | Acer | Aspire | finish |
| 4 | 1 | Acer | Aspire | on-going |

I used the following query to do that.

```
SELECT T1.m_id, T1.child_id, T2.make, T2.model, T1.op_status
FROM parent T1, child T2
WHERE T1.m_id = T2.m_id
```

But didn't get the disired above output and returns the result set as follows :

| m_id | child_id | make | model | op_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Acer | Aspire | finish |

What might be missed by myself ? Can help anyone on this ?

### Output as per Chiara Tumminelli's suggestion.

| m_id | child_id | make | model | op_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Acer | Aspire | finish |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | finish |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | finish |
| 4 | 1 | NULL | NULL | on-going |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your consecutive m_id values are associated to the same instance when child_id values are all null (before another non-null value), you can carry out this task with two joins to match:

- table1 parent m_id with table1 child m_id
- table1 child m_id with table2 m_id

```
SELECT t11.m_id, 
       t11.child_id,
       t2.make,
       t2.model,
       t11.op_status
FROM       tab1 t11 
INNER JOIN tab1 t12
        ON t11.m_id >= t12.child_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT m_id, make, model FROM tab2) t2
        ON t12.child_id = t2.m_id
```

**Output**:

| m_id | child_id | op_status | make | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | finish | Acer | Aspire |
| 2 | null | finish | Acer | Aspire |
| 3 | null | finish | Acer | Aspire |
| 4 | 1 | on-going | Acer | Aspire |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3WWxSCviviD1etAukR1QCj/0).

---

If you have a more complex gaps-and-islands problem, you may need to regenerate your partitions (m_id unique values) by:

- create a flag that indicates when to change partition
- compute a running sum over your flag
- gather the corresponding values of make, model, for each of your partitions

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t11.m_id, 
           t11.op_status,
           CASE WHEN t12.child_id IS NOT NULL 
                  OR LAG(t11.child_id) OVER(ORDER BY t11.m_id) IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
           END AS change_part,
           t11.child_id,
           t2.make,
           t2.model
    FROM      tab1 t11
    LEFT JOIN tab1 t12
           ON t11.m_id = t12.child_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT m_id, make, model FROM tab2) t2
           ON t12.child_id = t2.m_id
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT m_id, 
           op_status, 
           child_id, 
           make, 
           model,
           SUM(change_part) OVER(ORDER BY m_id) AS parts
    FROM cte
)
SELECT m_id, 
       op_status, 
       child_id,
       MAX(make)     OVER(PARTITION BY parts) AS make,
       MAX(model)    OVER(PARTITION BY parts) AS model
FROM cte2
ORDER BY m_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3WWxSCviviD1etAukR1QCj/2).